# Merge list of objects in terraform

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to merge the following list of objects

```
variable "common_variables" {
  type = list(object({ var_name = string, var_value = string, workspace_name = string }))
  default = [
    {
      "var_name"       = "location"
      "var_value"      = "West US"
      "workspace_name" = "env-1"
    }
  ]
}

variable "custom_variables" {
  type = list(object({ var_name = string, var_value = string, workspace_name = string }))
  default = [
    {
      "var_name"       = "location"
      "var_value"      = "West Europe"
      "workspace_name" = "env-1"
    }
  ]
}


locals {

  # custom_variables should replace common_variables
  merged_variables = concat(var.common_variables, var.custom_variables)

}

output "merged_variables" {
  value = local.merged_variables
}
```

Any `custom_variables` should replace `common_variables` that match on `workspace_name` & `var_name`.

So the output I want is:

```
merged_variables = [
  {
    "var_name" = "location"
    "var_value" = "West Europe"
    "workspace_name" = "env-1"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `setunion` https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/setunion.html

Usage:

```
locals {
    all_users = setunion(var.restricted_users, var.admin_users)
}
```

Variable types used for this case

```
variable "restricted_users" {
  type = set(object({
    email = string
    name  = string
    roles = set(string)
  }))

  default = []
}

variable "admin_users" {
  type = set(object({
    email = string
    name  = string
    roles = set(string)
  }))

  default = []
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do a merge-and-replace is to work with a map rather than a list, so I think I'd start by projecting the two lists into maps where the keys uniquely identify them by the values you want to use to decide what to override, using [`for` expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions):

```
locals {
  common_variables_map = { for v in var.common_variables : "${v.workspace_name}/${v.var_name}" => v }
  custom_variables_map = { for v in var.custom_variables : "${v.workspace_name}/${v.var_name}" => v }
}
```

We can then use the maps with [`merge`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/merge.html) to get the overriding behavior you want, and then convert back to a list with [`values`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/values.html) if necessary:

```
locals {
  merged_variables_map = merge(
    local.common_variables_map,
    local.custom_variables_map,
  )
  merged_variables = toset(values(merged_variables_map))
}
```

It's important to note that converting to a map like this will lose the original ordering of the given lists, because maps are not ordered. The items after merging may therefore be in a different order than the items in `var.common_variables` or `var.custom_variables`, and so I made that explicit by converting the result for local.merged_variables using [`toset`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/toset.html). If you consider that okay because the inputs are considered to be ordered anyway, you could make that more explicit to your module's caller by using a set type instead of a list type for the variables too:

```
variable "common_variables" {
  type = set(object({ var_name = string, var_value = string, workspace_name = string }))
  default = [
    {
      "var_name"       = "location"
      "var_value"      = "West US"
      "workspace_name" = "env-1"
    }
  ]
}

variable "custom_variables" {
  type = set(object({ var_name = string, var_value = string, workspace_name = string }))
  default = [
    {
      "var_name"       = "location"
      "var_value"      = "West Europe"
      "workspace_name" = "env-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Sets are not ordered either, so marking a variable as having a set type lets the caller know that the order of the objects is not significant. Terraform can automatically convert from a list to a set (by discarding the ordering), so this won't change the syntax for using the module.

Answer (score 0):

## Merging the lists

Here is a solution that preserves the order (the essential trick is boldly stolen from Martin's answer)

```
locals {
  common_variables_map = { for v in var.common_variables : "${v.workspace_name}/${v.var_name}" => v }
  custom_variables_map = { for v in var.custom_variables : "${v.workspace_name}/${v.var_name}" => v }
  common_keys          = [ for v in var.common_variables : "${v.workspace_name}/${v.var_name}" ]
  custom_keys          = [ for v in var.common_variables : "${v.workspace_name}/${v.var_name}" ]
  all_keys             = distinct(concat(common_keys, custom_keys))
  
  merged = [
    for k in local.all_keys:
      contains(common_variables_map, k) ? common_variables_map[k] : custom_variables_map[k]
  ]
}
```

## Restructuring variables

As an alternative you might want to consider restructuring your variables a bit and to provide them through input files. If you provide parameters to terraform like this

```
terraform apply -var-file="common.tfvars" -var-file="custom.tfvars"
```

then variables declared in both files will be taken from the file listed last.
For this to work you of cause need to break down the single list you have into individual parameters. In addition you might want to use a different file for different cases, e.g. use a different file depending on the workspace (it might be an option to wrap the call to terraform with a batch or shell-script or a make-file to make this more convenient).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you want, but you can use `map(string)` instead of `list(object...))`.

Here's how:

```
variable "custom_variables" {
  type    = map(string)
  default = {}
}
locals{
  common_variables = merge(
    {
      Environment     = local.env
      Deployment_type = "terraform"
      var_value       = "West Europe"
    },
    var.custom_variables
  )
}
```

Then, if you set the variable in `terraform.tfvars` or any var file like `var_value`, it should overwrite your commom_variables or add the new one.
For example

```
custom_variables={
  "var_value" = "West US"
}
```

That's basically the same thing @martin-atkins said.